# Apache log path - менять путь до access логов в зависимости от заголовка Host

Tags: linux, apache2, логирование

Задача:
В зависимости, от того куда пришел запрос в apache (на какой hostname), писать логи в файл который будет содержать в имени лога - заголовок host или ServerName или %{HTTP_HOST}
В данном примере я подразумеваю, что используется %{HTTP_HOST}

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.10:8888>
  UseCanonicalName Off

  ServerName test.example.ru
  ServerAlias test1.example.ru test2.example.ru

  VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%1/html

  CustomLog "/home/logs/%{HTTP_HOST}-access.log" combined
```

В данном случае:

Если запрос пришел на test1.example.ru, лог должен писаться в: `/home/logs/test1.example.ru-access.log`.

Если запрос пришел на test2.example.ru то соответственно в:
`/home/logs/test2.example.ru-access.log`.

Какими способами можно реализовать?

В частности еще интересует, указывать эту же логику для php логов

```
  <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value error_log "/home/logs/php/%{HTTP_HOST}-www-error_php.log"
    php_admin_value log_errors 1
  </IfModule>
```

Debian 7
Apache2 2.2.22-13

Comment: Вариант разделить `VirtualHost` на кол-во `ServerName` и в каждом прописать свой файл - вам не подходит?

Comment: @МАН69К Нет, это избыточное количество записей в конфиге, доменов может быть и более 15, a `ServerAlias *.example.ru` может иметь wildcard. В данном примере я специально указал лишь три домена.